# PHP Form, when no text is entered

Tags: php, forms

I'm creating a mobile landing page and I have also created a form that allows me to create more, by duplicating a folder that's host to a template file. The script then takes you to a page where you input the company details one by one and press submit. Then the page is created.

My problem is, when a field is left out (YouTube for instance), the button is created and is blank. I would like there to be a default text for when there is no text. I've tried a few things and have been struggling to make this work for DAYS!

```
    <?php 
$company = $_POST["company"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$colour = $_POST["colour"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$website = $_POST["website"];
$video = $_POST["video"];
?>

<div id="contact-area">

<form method="post" action="generate.php"><br>
<input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" /><br>
<input type="text" name="slogan" placeholder="Slogan" /><br>
<input class="color {required:false}" name="colour" placeholder="Company Colour"><br>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" /><br>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" /><br>
<input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Full Website - Include http://" /><br>
<input type="text" name="video" placeholder="Video URL" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Generate QuickLinks" style="background:url(images/submit.png) repeat-x; color:#FFF"/>
</form>
```

That's the form. It takes the variables and post's them to the file below.

```
<?php 
 $File = "includes/details.php"; 
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 ?>

 <?php 
 $File = "includes/details.php";
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 $Data = "<div id='logo'>
          <h1 style='color:#$_POST[colour]'>$_POST[company]</h1>
          <h2>$_POST[slogan]</h2>
          </div>

<ul data-role='listview' data-inset='true' data-theme='b'>
       <li style='background-color:#$_POST[colour]'><a href='tel:$_POST[phone]'>Phone Us</a></li>
       <li style='background-color:#$_POST[colour]'><a href='mailto:$_POST[email]'>Email Us</a></li>
       <li style='background-color:#$_POST[colour]'><a href='$_POST[website]'>View Full Website</a></li>
       <li style='background-color:#$_POST[colour]'><a href='$_POST[video]'>Watch Us</a></li>
       </ul>

 \n";

 fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
 fclose($Handle); 
 ?>
```

and there is what the form turns into. I need there to be a default link put in incase the field is left blank, witch it is sometimes. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1):

Just use something like this for every element:

```
    $company = trim($_POST["company"]);

    if (!isset($company) || empty($company)) {
        $company = "Not filled in";
    }
```

I added trim to make sure spaces are ignored

Comment: Doesn't that have exactly the same issue with spaces as strlen?

Answer (score 0):

Use following format for each variables:

> $company = (isset($_POST["company"]) && !empty($_POST["company"]))? $_POST["company"]:"";

"" at the end of the can assign any default values.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually easier to work with post variables if you wrap the access in a function:

```
function post($key, $default = '') {
  if (!isset($_POST[$key])) return $default;

  $value = trim($_POST[$key]);
  if ($value == '')
    return $default;
  else
    return $value;
}
```

You can now assign your variables like this:

```
$company = post('company');
$phone = post('phone', 'Not provided');
$colour = post('colour', 'blue');
... and so on...
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you get away with simply wrapping your variable definitions in code like:

```
if (strlen($_POST["company"]) > 0) {
    $company = $_POST["company"];
} else {
    $company = "default company";
}
```

That will let you specify a default value that will be over-written by the user's data if there is any.

Comment: strlen seems a bit like a bad way to check.. what if I enter spaces?