# if $var==blank set make it "XXX"?

Tags: php, forms

Hello and good morning to all. This is my second post on this subject because the first time, things still didn't work and I have now literally been trying to solve this for about 4/5 days straight...

I have a file, called 'edit.php', in this file is a form;

```
<?php 
$company = $_POST["company"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];
$colour = $_POST["colour"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$website = $_POST["website"];
$video = $_POST["video"];
$image = $_POST["image"];
$extension = $_POST["extension"];
?>

<form method="post" action="generate.php"><br>
<input type="text" name="company" placeholder="Company Name" /><br>
<input type="text" name="slogan" placeholder="Slogan" /><br>
<input class="color {required:false}" name="colour" placeholder="Company Colour"><br>
<input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" /><br>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" /><br>
<input type="text" name="website" placeholder="Full Website - Include http://" /><br>
<input type="text" name="video" placeholder="Video URL" /><br>
<input type="submit" value="Generate QuickLinks" style="background:url(images/submit.png) repeat-x; color:#FFF"/>
</form>
```

Then, when the form is submitted, it creates a file using the variables that have been input. The fields that have been filled in go on to become links, I need to be able to say 'if a field is left blank, then put 'XXX' in as a default value'. Does anyone have any ideas? I really think I have tried everything. I'll put below a snippet from the .php file that generates the links...

```
<?php 
 $File = "includes/details.php"; 
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 ?>

 <?php 
 $File = "includes/details.php";
 $Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
 $Data = "<div id='logo'>
          <img width='270px' src='images/logo.png'/img>
          <h1 style='color:#$_POST[colour]'>$_POST[company]</h1>
          <h2>$_POST[slogan]</h2>
          </div>

<ul>
       <li><a class='full-width button' href='tel:$_POST[phone]'>Phone Us</a></li>
       <li><a class='full-width button' href='mailto:$_POST[email]'>Email Us</a></li>
       <li><a class='full-width button' href='$_POST[website]'>View Full Website</a></li>
       <li><a class='full-width button' href='$_POST[video]'>Watch Us</a></li>
</ul>

 \n";
```

I really do look forward to any response...

Comment: There's an XSS security hole in your code: don't plainly echo `$_POST` variables, but use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Comment: @admin user is no more on SO. shoud we answer?

Comment: @diEcho Yes, it is a migrated question and he probably has never been on SO, but he will be redirected from his original question.

Comment: @diEcho Apparently the question was migrated from **webmasters.stackexchange.com** and the OP has a registered account there...

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Form, when no text is entered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11142588/php-form-when-no-text-is-entered)

Comment: What's the contents of includes/details.php?

Answer (score 2):

Well this is pretty simple.

In your php, check if it's empty:

(I will demonstrate with the phone number input)

```
if(empty($_POST['phone']))

//so here, you know it's empty (has a value of "") so now you can set it to whatever...
$phone="xxx";

}//end of empty phone
else{

$phone=$_POST['phone'];//set it

}//end of phone input not empty
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to replace

```
$_POST[varname]
```

with

```
($_POST[varname]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST[varname]) : 'XXXX';
```

which is the short version of

```
if(isset($_POST[varname]))
    htmlspecialchars($_POST[varname]);
else
    'XXXX';
```

Hope that helps you.